# Is it possible to dimm a model except the objects NOT affected by setThemingColor?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We use the viewer (version 7) to show the issues on 3d model colouring the affected objects using a user defined palette.

The remainig objects of the model are colored with a gray tone.
To achieve this I'm using the setThemingColor technique: I set the theming color grey for the rootid recursive and then I set the correct theme color to the specific issued object.

All the colors used are THREE.Vector4 with the opacity set to 1. In this way the themingColor is non blended with the "natural" color of the object but it "covers" object.

To improve the user experience we'd like to allow the user to dimm the objects not affected by issue instead of set the gray color using setThemingColor.

And now the question: is it possible to change the color (material?) of a group of objects by specifying a fade level up to the ghost of the viewer hide method while preserving the selection functionality?

I have tried the following approach with no success:

```js
        const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, opacity: 0.925, transparent: false });
        (this.viewer as any).impl.getMaterials().addMaterial('ghost-material', mat, true);
        
        const model = (this.viewer as any).model;
        const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
        const frags = model.getFragmentList();


        [19240, 20373, 34364, 58813].map(dbid => {
            tree.enumNodeFragments(dbid, (fragid) => {
                console.log(fragid);
                frags.setMaterial(fragid, mat);
                (this.viewer as any).impl.invalidate(true);
            }, true);
        });
```

[19240, 20373, 34364, 58813] are valid dbids.
The opacity is almost 1 and the material is not transparent hoping to see something.
I tried to invalidate the viewer for each fragment.
After running this script, the 3d model remains the same.
The 'ghost-material' is regularly registered on matman but does not 'replace' the native one.

Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to do is to call the method:

```js
model.unconsolidate(); // If the model is consolidated, material changes won't have any effect
```

before apply the new material to the fragments as explained in the following post

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-shader-materials-forge-viewer

The right answer is

```js
        const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, opacity: 0.925, transparent: false });
        (this.viewer as any).impl.getMaterials().addMaterial('ghost-material', mat, true);
        
        const model = (this.viewer as any).model;
        const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
        const frags = model.getFragmentList();

        // without this it is all useless
        model.unconsolidate();

        [19240, 20373, 34364, 58813].map(dbid => {
            tree.enumNodeFragments(dbid, (fragid) => {
                console.log(fragid);
                frags.setMaterial(fragid, mat);
                (this.viewer as any).impl.invalidate(true);
            }, true);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a bit of an advanced topic but you *can* customize materials assigned to individual objects (fragments). The process would be as follows:

- Create a custom, semi-transparent material, e.g., a simple `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial`, and add it to the viewer's material manager
- Use the instance tree to enumerate fragments of all objects in your scene
- Use the fragment list to retrieve the original material of each fragment, store its reference somewhere, and set its material to your custom one

The code could look roughly like so:

```js
const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, opacity: 0.25, transparent: true });
viewer.impl.getMaterials().addMaterial('my-material', mat, true);
const tree = viewer.model.getInstanceTree();
const frags = viewer.model.getFragmentList();
tree.enumNodeFragments(tree.getRootId(), (fragid) => { frags.setMaterial(fragid, mat) }, true);
```

When needed, repeat the process, and reset each fragment to its original material.

Comment: This is the approach I have used but with no success. I have edited my question mentioning your advice